# Spring validations -> @NotNull on nested objects with BigDecimal

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, request, spring-validation

I have POST endpoint that creates for example Books,
in CreateBookRequest class I have another nested class/record that holds BigDecimal price.
I want to secure this endpoint so json's (given below) will be validated as BAD_REQUEST (with custom exception will be great).

My structure:

```java
  @PostMapping(path = "/books", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  ResponseEntity<Void> createBook(@Valid @RequestBody CreateBookRequest request);

  public record CreateBookRequest(

      @Valid
      @NotNull
      Price price

  ) {
  }

  public record Price(
      @NotNull
      BigDecimal value
  ) {
  }
```

Correct JSON:

```json
{
  "price": {
    "value": 60.00
  }
}
```

Invaluid JSON's:

```json
{
  "price": null
}
```

```json
{
  "price": ""
}
```

```json
{}
```

My structure with validation annotations does not work at this time, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case code was fine, the missing part was the dependency:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Written a small app using spring boot 3.0.0 and JDK 19 and everything worked perfectly fine for me. Here are the snippets

```
@RestController
public class BookController {
    @PostMapping(path = "/books", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> createBook(@Valid @RequestBody CreateBookRequest request){
        if(request.getPrice().value() != null){
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Good request");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Check the request");
    }
}


import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
public class CreateBookRequest {
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    Price price;
    public Price getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(Price price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}


public record Price(
        @NotNull
        BigDecimal value
) {
    public Price(BigDecimal value){
        this.value = value;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, for me it was the missing dependencyu.